# How can I convert XML to UTF-8 and retain header

Tags: xml, powershell

I am attempting to convert XML to UTF-8 and create a new directory for the converted files.

Using the code below it successfully creates UTF-8 XML files however it leaves out the

```xml
<!DOCTYPE dmodule[
!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/ent/ISOEntities" %ISOEntities;
]>
```

which we need because information is placed there for images.

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\source\*.xml"
$output = "C:\changed\"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
    $doc.set_PreserveWhiteSpace($true);
    $doc.Load($file);

    $root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
    $xml = $root.Get-Content $file;
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + $xml

    $newFile = $output + $file.Name
    Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $newFile $xml;
}
```

Expected result is to retain the entire document or at least get and add the header data back in after conversion.

Comment: What does the xml file look like?

Comment: Doctype follows the header <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>, which I am replacing as you can see, and everything after the entity is converting just fine.  Just need to either include this portion or get the content and copy it in on the back side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's my example.

```
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd"[]>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Add a line in the beginning and save as utf8.  The way you add it, it becomes a string, not an array of strings.  Actually that would work, but it would all be on one line in the file.

```
$xml = get-content $file
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',$xml
set-content $newfile $xml -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that I don't lose the doctype tag like this.  You don't need to do this.

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$xml.save($file)
```

Loading and saving it that way will also change the encoding according to the xml tag.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm not quite following though, are you saying to add the line in the beginning of the foreach loop?  Also, instead of "file.xml", this should just be $file I assume?

Comment: I changed the answer to match your variables.

Comment: Actually, when I use your doctype tag, I get an error.  "Expected DTD
markup was not found. Line 3, position 1."

Comment: No worries, your answer is helpful.  Thank you.